# Wordpress / Yoast SEO: Open Graph tags not showing on portfolio items

Tags: wordpress, hook, facebook-opengraph, yoast

I'd like to add open graph meta tags to the portfolio items on my Wordpress website. I'm using the Yoast SEO Plugin.

It will add open graph (fb/twitter) meta tags to the **posts and pages**.
For example:

```
    <meta name="description" content="Wedding Invitation Templates in Word" />
    <link rel="canonical" href="https://www.temploola.com/wedding-invitation-templates/" />
    <meta property="og:locale" content="en_US" />
    <meta property="og:type" content="article" />
    <meta property="og:title" content="✩✩Free Word Templates for Wedding Invitations✩✩" />`
```

But it's not added to the **portfolio items**. For example on:

https://www.temploola.com/wedding-invitations/item/geometric-winter-template/

Any idea to add this. Perhaps via functions.php?

```
add_action('wp_head', 'add_one_wpseo_og', 1);
function add_one_wpseo_og() { 
if ( is_mokaine_portfolio_post() ) {
add_action( 'wpseo_head', array( $GLOBALS['wpseo_og'], 'opengraph' ), 30   );
}
```